# alternatives to jenkins in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

I am looking for some continuous integration solutions in AWS which can replace jenkins . Since my software is completely in AWS , i am looking for some thing with in AWS itself. I have heard of AWS Code deploy etc. 
Please throw some lights.

Answer (score 4):

AWS recently announced [AWS CodeStar](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-codestar/) to develop, build, and deploy applications with CI/CD, utilizing AWS Code Pipeline, Code Build & Code Deploy. It also comes with [predefined templates](https://console.aws.amazon.com/codestar/home?region=us-east-1#/quickstart) that provides appropriate selection of tooling based on Technology requirements.

Answer (score 2):

AWS CodeDeploy isn't a *CI* tool; it's a *CD* tool. They have something called **CodePipeline**, but that is simply a service that allows you to string together a bunch of different tools (some AWS, some not, including Jenkins for CI) to accomplish what you can with a Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: I basically want my application to be built from GIT and deploy it to AWS EBS. Can any of this pull code from GIT , build it and deploy to AWS EBS?

Comment: CodePipeline can do it, but their examples all leverage Jenkins. I know it's probably not what you want to hear, but I do everything with Jenkins and use aws cli commands in my scripts to perform my infrastructure automation and deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You may use AWS CodePipeline (along with CodeDeploy) for deploying your application wherever you like. It works pretty well but without Jenkins you won't be able to run any test before actual deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question really needs clarification in terms of what you mean by 'continuous integration,' and what you mean by 'in AWS.'

**What does continuous integration mean to you?**

Integration typically just means the ability to merge code from multiple developers, execute unit tests, and perhaps run some quality control auditing tools like SonarQube. If the code compiles and the basic tests pass, then your developers have successfully 'integrated' their code.

AWS CodePipeline can handle this and more. It can go beyond and do staging and push to production. That pushes toward the idea of continuous delivery as well.

[image]

**What do you mean by 'within AWS?'**

As far as [Jenkins alternative](https://www.theserverside.com/tip/5-Jenkins-alternatives-for-Java-developers) 'within AWS', I guess it all depends on what you mean by 'within AWS.' If you specifically want an AWS product, CodePipeline is probably your only choice. But you might find a nice [CI/CD Bitnami stack](https://bitnami.com/stacks) you could just deploy [as a container](https://www.theserverside.com/video/How-to-deploy-Docker-Hub-hosted-microservices-in-AWS-ECS) to the AWS Elastic Container Service, and then you've got a bit more control over the offering, and it still meets your 'within AWS' requirement.